# What Swashbuckler build has the maximum attack bonus?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, feats, optimization

I am creating a Swashbuckler build and need help optimising for maximum attack bonus. This will be a level 20 build and should use the inspired blade archetype.

#### Character Concept

I intend to build a challenger who takes down his foes 1 on 1 and try to settle things down by dueling. Focusing on humanoids. An arena warrior who fights for money. Opportunist riposte would be his main weapon in the arena (that's the reason why the max attack bonus) to try to get by most battles unscathed.

#### Rules

- All Pathfinder content is allowed.
- Any race is allowed.
- Build should be level 20.
- Build should use Swashbuckler (inspired blade archetype) as main class
- Some multi-classing allowed
- No flanking or buffs from allies
- Use Opportunist Riposte as main attack method.
- Must be a 1-v-1 specialist

#### Things I've considered

**Feats:** Weapon Focus, Greater Weapon Focus, Desperate Battler, Fencing Grace.

**Magic Items:** Belts of physical enhancements, Headband if the class gets any pros from int, wis, cha, Stats manuals/tomes, Magic weapons, Boots of speed, Bracers of sworn vengeance.

**With these rules, what Swashbuckler build has the maximum attack bonus?**

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have edited the question. Have been playing rpgs since the early 90s, but mostly storyteller. I used to play a lot of adnd back then, but my experience since the 3rd edition comes mostly from computer games. I'm rather new to Pathfinder and find this system fascinating.

Comment: My focus is on Pathfinder, Linkssassin. I think the system is kinda balanced. DnD seemed too overpowered in terms of combos and stuff to me. But my experience comes mostly from every DnD pc game I played. I could build some rather absurd chars combining some broken feats and items.

Comment: I've rewritten the question to focus on the build in a more stack exchange style question. Requests for tips or advice don't suit this site very well. If you disagree with anything I've done please edit the question. I will hold my reopen vote until you have confirm this is the question you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and your opinions on the systems too. I'm quite unexperienced in the post adnd era, sincerely. We played mostly storyteller system and rules. But we did some crossover with forgotten realms, too. Lol

Comment: Note, some people may still consider this question too broad. If you have any more restrictions or rules [edit] them into the question. Also once this gets reopened don't expect a quick answer. Pathfinder build questions can take awhile.

Comment: @Daniel As far as optimization goes, Classes rarely effect your attack bonus (out side of the base attack bonus). In this case your question should be what are great ways of increase bonus to hit (As the swashbuckler class by itself has no other control over it), and that would be too broad.